# Oracle dynamic query (return or select) result as table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How can I show the result of running a dynamic query as a table in the output?

I want to show the result of the following query as a table in the output.

**my table** :

```
create table myTable(ROW_NAME varchar(10),COLUMN_NAME varchar(10),COLUMN_NAME_VALUE varchar(10));
```

**table data** :

```
insert into myTable (ROW_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_NAME_VALUE)
select 'ROW1','COL1','R1C1' from dual
union all select 'ROW1','COL2','R1C2' from dual
union all select 'ROW1','COL3','R1C3' from dual
union all select 'ROW2','COL1','R2C1' from dual
union all select 'ROW2','COL2','R2C2' from dual
union all select 'ROW2','COL3','R2C3' from dual
union all select 'ROW3','COL1','R3C1' from dual
union all select 'ROW3','COL2','R3C3' from dual
union all select 'ROW3','COL3','R3C3' from dual
```

**my dynamic query** :

```
DECLARE
   mycols VARCHAR2(1000);
   sqlCommand varchar2(1000);
   TYPE PivotCurTyp IS REF CURSOR;
   pivot_cv   PivotCurTyp;
   type pivotted is record (row_name myTable.row_name%type, col1 myTable.column_name_value%type, col2 myTable.column_name_value%type, col3 myTable.column_name_value%type);
   piv_rec  pivotted;
BEGIN
    select (select LISTAGG('''' || COLUMN_NAME || '''', ',') from myTable group by ROW_NAME FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY) into mycols from dual;
    select Concat('select * from myTable pivot ( max (COLUMN_NAME_VALUE) for COLUMN_NAME in (',Concat(mycols,')) ORDER BY ROW_NAME')) into sqlCommand from dual;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlCommand);
   OPEN pivot_cv FOR sqlCommand;
   LOOP
     FETCH pivot_cv INTO piv_rec;
     EXIT WHEN pivot_cv%NOTFOUND;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ROW_NAME: ' || piv_rec.ROW_NAME || ' COL1: ' ||
         piv_rec.COL1 || ' COL2: ' || piv_rec.COL2 || ' COL3: ' || piv_rec.COL3);
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE pivot_cv;
END;
/
```

demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2cf53698d743f842fe1ab1af0ecb86e4)

Thanks for any help

Comment: You might be able to do [something like this](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_HPN95108FSSZD87PXX7MG3LW3.html) using a polymorphic table function (18c+). It's not straightforward though.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson SQL Server also easily generates code, meaning there is no simple solution

Comment: I don't follow. Why does that mean there is no simple solution?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Oracle, and by referring to the link you provided, I said and panicked that there was no simple solution.

Comment: Do you actually want to print the output in one column, or are you looking for a dynamic number of columns? If you need a dynamic number of columns, maybe [this project](https://github.com/method5/method4) can help?

Comment: I want to use the select command instead of DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE

Comment: @MeysamAsadi Usually this type of problem is best solved in the application layer, perhaps with a SYS_REFCUSOR. If you really need a pure SELECT statement that returns a dynamic number of columns, you'll need PL/SQL objects, such as the polymorphic table function that William suggested, or an Oracle Data Cartridge type I mentioned in my last comment. Can you install custom PL/SQL objects? (Also, try searching for "dynamic pivot" for other questions about this topic.)

Comment: @JonHeller No, I do not work as an oracle specialist and I encountered this problem to help a friend and I wanted Query to generate columns dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstood, I guess what you want is this?

```sql
select 'ROW_NAME ' || t1.row_name || ' ' || listagg(t1.column_name || ': ' || t1.column_name_value, ' ') 
       within group(order by t1.column_name)
  from myTable t1
 group by t1.row_name
 order by t1.row_name
```